# SQL Data Reader (NpgsqlDataReader) skipping 1st line

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, sqldatareader

So I have a pretty simple reader, which executes given query:

```
            connection.Open();
            using (var r = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var item in r)
                    {
                        var listOfValues = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)item;
                        result.Add(VisualTsTableMapper.MapFromDbRecord(listOfValues));
                    }
                };
            }
            connection.Close();
```

As from database, I am getting 4 rows of results. Although after reading I retrieve only 3. What do I do wrong?
[image]

[image]

Comment: *Either* enumerate the data reader, *or* use a loop with `.Read()` (or better yet, eliminate this boilerplate altogether and use Dapper). Enumeration implicitly starts off with a `.Read()`, so you're discarding the first row.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Is Dapper capable of executing PostgreSQL custom functions?

Comment: Dapper is a lightweight wrapper around ADO.NET, and Npgsql is an ADO.NET driver. If your function access can be written as a query, it will work. The Npgsql docs show nothing special here (except for not having proper support for `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, apparently); use `SELECT`/`CALL` as appropriate.